# align two polygons, there are the same but one polygon is damaged

Tags: python

I have two polygons that made from a number of points. As shown in the image:

[image]

Suppose a is equal to a' and b is equal to b' and c is not the same as c'. Is there any way that I can align the left polygon with the right polygon? I learn that I can check where they are aligned by calculating the intersection area of two polygons. If the intersection area is the same as the left polygon, they are aligned. However, I cannot find any algorithm that can merge to the result. Has anyone any good ideas? Thank you so much!

Comment: What are the possible ways that it could be damaged?  Also, by align do you mean match up the vertices?

Comment: Actually, by damage, I mean one vertex is not the same as the vertex on another polygon, but other vertices are the same. Yes, by align, I mean match up the vertices. Thank you!